# Using Japanese letters in the username

Tags: support, display-names

I got the following error:

> **Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:**
>
> - Display Name can only
>   contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start
>   with a letter or digit

after I tried to set my username using Japanese letters: `イオニカ・ビザウ`.

Which of them cannot be used?

I cannot try every letter to see if it pass the validation because I cannot save my username again, then.

Comment: Yet your username already uses Katakana now (`ツ`). Perhaps it's the `・`? Or perhaps you cannot start the username with a Katakana character (such as `イ`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, maybe. I don't risk to change it and then to not be able to change it again. :-) It would be nice to make an open source validator for SE usernames.

Comment: It is the `・`: http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/36995

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that means that `・` is not a valid letter?

Comment: This post is actually a little extra entertaining if you don't have the character set installed on your computer.  Every character you are discussing is just a rectangle -- it's great.

Comment: Hiragana works. Unless you're @BlackVegetable. In which case, the question should be "Using rectangles in the username".  :)

Comment: Ionica Bizau? What the dickens...?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is the `・` (U+30FB Katakana middle dot, category "Po, Other_Punctuation") codepoint that is not allowed.

Use a space instead, Katakana letters themselves are perfectly valid:

[image: me on UX]

The name is filtered with the [.NET `\w` character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax) which includes any Unicode letter categories (Ll, Lu, Lt, Lo, Lm), connecting characters (Pc, connecting punctuation, underscores really) and numbers (Nd), with a dash of hyphen, space and apostrophe thrown in; Katakana characters are "Lo, Other_Letter" for example.