# Allow Chinese names with less than 3 characters on Chinese Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, display-names, unicode

...and possibly elsewhere on the network, but I really think it should at least be allowed on [Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/).

I and many others are not able to use our names on Chinese Stack Exchange without romanising them (for example, my name is 赵永) because such names are less than 3 characters, which is very common for Chinese names.

Can we please allow such names, at least on sites that are dedicated to Chinese language and culture?

Comment: Usernames are filtered with the [.NET `\w` character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax) which includes any Unicode letter categories (Ll, Lu, Lt, Lo, Lm), connecting characters (Pc, connecting punctuation, underscores really) and numbers (Nd), with a dash of hyphen, space and apostrophe thrown in. I guess Chinese glyphs are not included in that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I more or less understand the technical reasons why this occurs, my main concern is about creating positive impact for Chinese Stack Exchange users. :-)

Comment: Sure, just documenting the exact rules as they stand now.

Comment: [U+8d75 赵 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8D75](http://codepoints.net/U+8d75) is Letter Other (Lo), so it *should* be allowed to be used as the start of a name. It seems the only limitation you are facing is the 3 character minimum.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No worries, I appreciate your input. I believe this policy exists to avoid people using Unicode characters of significance that might cause problems (for example, adding a moderator symbol, or sending text directionality information). I don't think there are Chinese characters that would do that, but I'd be interested in hearing insights in case this was intentional.

Comment: Chinese characters *are allowed* as they are generally Lo (Other Letter) characters. See [Using Japanese letters in the username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204589) as well, where Japanese Katakana was used, which are in the same Lo category.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's my bad -- I tried "赵永/Chris Down" and the real reason it rejected it was because of the "/", not "赵" at the beginning. Too bad that the error message ("Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit") is extremely vague about the reason you weren't allowed to use that name (Chinese characters are not "letters"), which makes it a little confusing. :-( I'll update the question.

Comment: Sorry, Chinese characters do indeed have the Unicode `General Category = Other Letter` character property, which means that they are indeed `gc=Letter`, and so you will lose your battle trying to say that they are not letters.  Unicode says they are, and that is all that matters here.  If you want a two-character username, choose two characters from above the BMP, since  the SE character-counting code is broken (**they’re counting *code units* not *code points*, how embarrassing!**) and because it erroneously counts two such characters as four, you will sneak past the guardians at the gate.

Comment: This has been on my list for a while, but I unfortunately got sidetracked by other projects. The goal here is to make 2+ characters the new minimum name length standard and I'll see if I can bump this up on my todo list in the near future.

Comment: @AnnaLear Awesome, thank you!

Comment: This feature is also requested on Stack Overflow for Japanese: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1655/19110

Comment: Related restriction: We cannot notify a user with less-than-three-letter display name in comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35913/341401