# Stack Overflow should not allow non-ASCII usernames!

Tags: discussion, display-names

I find this very unprofessional when people can choose any set of characters for their names.
This makes no fun when you try to tag them (using the @ symbol), or search them in the site.

It looks very bad also. Think of a site that looks like a soup of:

奇怪的用户名
اسم مستخدم غريب
ထူးဆန်းသောအသုံးပြုသူအမည်
విచిత్రమైన వినియోగదారు పేరు

Also keep in mind, some of them can have slurs and curse words, and *no one* will ever know. Because what are the chances that a moderator knows "Telugu language" (can you spot which one is it, really?)

Anyway, I find this unprofessional and not very nice.
Also - no, I can’t be asked to "copy" their name in order to tag them, or search, because you have the feature of auto-complete and I want to use it, and copying&pasting makes this feature useless.

Comment: If they have slurs or curse words, it needs to be pointed out, and all users are invited to fo just that. Besides, I don't think we can disallow certain characters just because some people want to 'abuse' the system.

Comment: What about the international sites? We do have sites in other languages; would you ban accent characters on [es.so] or [pt.so], Cyrillic characters on [ru.so] and [rus.se], or Japanese characters on [ja.so]? What about the various language sites (whose site UIs are in English), such as [french.se] or [japanese.se]?

Comment: _"2: explain why you don't agree."_ - I'd like if that'd worked.

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over. Starting points are *[What should be done about offensive names?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/)* and *[Why was my flag on an inappropriate username declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409112/)*. But the real purpose is trolling, I gather? Trolling is better reserved for other places, like YouTube comments or [4chan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4chan).

Comment: Ironically your user name is "Not professional" in English ...

Answer (score 13):

While SE is US based, and our sites are 'primarily' English, and the staff heavily based in the US and EU - the network and its community is diverse and not all in the anglophone sphere. We have sites in Russian (both language and programming) and Japanese (likewise) which have users who certainly may not be using Latin script as their primary language.

*If* someone's username is unprofessional and/or offensive, even if a *moderator* does not speak the language if a user knows it's offensive they can highlight it via a flag. Where practicable, we *can* tap on mods who can read a language or make the determination ourselves.

Not being in English *doesn't* mean unprofessional.

Interestingly - I tried changing the username on a alternate account I use for testing from aibobot to ஐபோபோட் and failed so there may be rules to what characters an account can use.

Comment: "Aipōpōṭ"? When did "b" become "p"? :)

Comment: Close as I could get. There's no real 'b' sound in tamil

Comment: There are rules, yes: [Using Japanese letters in the username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204590); you can use any character in the [.NET \w character class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax).

Comment: Since `ஐபோபோட்` contains two *U+0BCB TAMIL VOWEL SIGN OO* codepoints (which are Unicode category Mc, or *Mark, spacing combining* codepoints) and one *U+0BCD TAMIL SIGN VIRAMA* codepoint (category Mn, *Mark, nonspacing*), it fails to match the regex.

Comment: Ah, found my original source for the regex class: [What characters are allowed for the display name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106339)